# can we find the number of element in a structure at run-time in C?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

I wanted to know, is there a way to find the number of members/ elements in a structure, also, either data type/ size of that element at run-time?

consider a random structure:

```
struct ABC {
    int x;
    char y;
    float z;
};
```

At runtime, all I know is the structure name 'ABC'. So, with the help of either pointers or something is there a way to find out that the following structure contains 3 element with their respective type (int, char and float)?

Comment: Why do you want the "number" of elements? What are you trying to achieve with this value?

Comment: You appear to be trying to solve a different problem. Are you familiar with the XY problem? [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: C doesn't have reflection, so no.

Comment: That feeling of void after using .Net reflection. Pity.

Comment: Why would you need reflection for that?

Comment: I probably meant Java, but I guess in C# there's a lot of abuse too.

Comment: on a request (via any communication protocol), I need to send the details of my defined structures. basically, in a patch-type firmware update, we keep the structure name same but some times we add some more elements in the structure too. hence, too ensure whether all the patch updates are properly working and fixed, I wanted to know the number element present in the structure.

Comment: You need to define a protocol yourself apparently. Or find one that fits your needs. You can only send bytes through a "request" if I understand correctly and I suspect you mean through a network connection probably tcp or udp. Just define a way to "_serialize_" your payload and one such that you can "_desirialize_" from the other end.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Yes, we've our set of protocols via serial UART and TCP communication, which is not a big problem. to ensure all the patch files is working and updated, there are some random checksums in the code. Now we wanted to add more features to increase the reliability even further.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi It wasn't me who was suggesting reflection - please read the comments carefully. I was merely wondering why reflection would be necessary for what the OP is asking for. In C++ [it _is_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding#Case_3:_binding_to_data_members) possible to use structured bindings to bind to struct data members, without reflection whatsoever.

Comment: @andreee Sorry, I meant to be sarcastic. Sorry if it was not obvious.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: Oh, I see :-) Thanks for clarifying...

Comment: @AatifShaikh: Not posting as an answer because it is C++ (but maybe still relevant for you): [These](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/639b20952176e397) are two ways of how it would look like in C++, without reflection whatsoever. Sorry I don't have a solution for C at hand (if that's possible at all...)

Answer (score 4):

Programatically no. Your binary could have some debug informations about these structures that could be reached through os but that are unavailable if you stream your structure somewhere. In every case that's **not** the way to achieve what you need.